# AWS S3: Lambda triggered on OBJECT_CREATED does not list the newly created object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created an S3 bucket with a lambda function that gets triggerde upon object creation.

I have set this up using CDK:

```py
class IndexedBucketStack(cdk.Stack):
    def __init__(
        self,
        scope: cdk.Construct,
        construct_id: str,
        site_name: str,
        hostname: str = None,
        **kwargs
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        # Bucket to store the files in.
        # Important here that we destroy the S3 Bucket when the stack would be deleted.
        bucket = s3.Bucket(
            self,
            "Bucket",
            website_index_document=INDEX_FILE_NAME,
            removal_policy=cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
        )

        # Lambda that builds an index page every time a file gets uploaded or changed
        create_index_lambda = _lambda.Function(
            # snipped the code out here, but essentially packages a python function
        )

        # Allow lambda function to read the bucket
        bucket.grant_read_write(create_index_lambda)

        # Add event notification that triggers our lambda upon object creation...
        bucket.add_event_notification(
            s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED, s3n.LambdaDestination(create_index_lambda)
        )

        # ... and one on deletion of an object.
        bucket.add_event_notification(
            s3.EventType.OBJECT_REMOVED, s3n.LambdaDestination(create_index_lambda)
        )
```

In the function, I list the objects using [cloudpathlib](https://cloudpathlib.drivendata.org/)'s iterdir().

Hoever the results of that list (which uses ListObects v1 if I have it correctly) sometimes does not contain that just created file.

So I could just put a delay inside the lambda, but that seems a waste of time / money, right?

The goal is to have a lambda that creates a directory index.html everytime a file gets uploaded to a folder.

Comment: If the problem is that your Lambda function doesn't report the file, why aren't you showing us the function (or at least a [Short, Self-Contained Example](http://sscce.org/) if you don't want to share your real code)? Have you verified that the function gets invoked _at all_? Have you verified that the function code is what you expect? If yes, then the CDK code is irrelevant.

Comment: The code you've shown is irrelevant. If you want help with the actual Lambda that's using cloudpathlib then you should post that code instead.

Comment: It was being invoked since I had debug statements printing the files. I would gladly update the question with the initial code but I don't have it anymore (didn't commit it).
I posted the CDK code because I thought it might have something to do with the type of Event Notification.
The issue was resolved by relying on ListObjectsV2 instead of V1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently ListObjects (v1) is not strong consistent, while ListObjectsV2 is. The latter gives the intended results.

I ended up using [S3Path](https://github.com/liormizr/s3path) instead of cloudpathlib, which does implement the V2 and offers the same convenience.

Comment: As of v0.11.0 `cloudpathlib` does use `ListObjectsV2`

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html new object should be passed in the notification event - no need to call S3 API to find it on a  list.

Comment: I know, but I want to build a total list of all the objects in that "directory". So I need the list event. I could check if the created object is in there, if not add it, and process that list, but seems hacky.

Comment: S3 should be strongly consistent according to https://aws.amazon.com/s3/consistency/ . So list should contain new object. Your solution might be the best one. Other one is delaying and retrying if object is not on the list.